# How do you properly call a function from the reducer/actions in this context?

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux, material-ui

The action/reducer i am trying to call isn't working. It doesn't seem to actually reading the function the way i am calling it. The problem is in deleteWorkout function.

Ive tried using mapDispatchToProps and I've tried calling the action directly from actions.
src - index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import allReducer from './reducers';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import throttle from 'lodash/throttle';
// import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import App from './App';
import { loadState, saveState } from './localStorage';

const persistedState = loadState();

const store = createStore(
    allReducer,
    persistedState,
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
);

store.subscribe(throttle(() => {
    saveState({
        workoutList: store.getState().workoutList
    });
}, 100));

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>, 
    document.getElementById('root')
);
// registerServiceWorker();
```

Reducer - index.js

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import switchLogin from './SwitchLogin'
import workoutList from './WorkoutList'
import { reducer as AddWorkout } from 'redux-form'

const allReducers = combineReducers({
    switchLogin,
    workoutList,
    form: AddWorkout,
})

export default allReducers;
```

WorkoutItem Class

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

import ExpansionPanel from "@material-ui/core/ExpansionPanel";
import ExpansionPanelSummary from "@material-ui/core/ExpansionPanelSummary";
import ExpansionPanelDetails from "@material-ui/core/ExpansionPanelDetails";
import ExpansionPanelActions from "@material-ui/core/ExpansionPanelActions";

import TableHead from "@material-ui/core/TableHead";
import TableBody from "@material-ui/core/TableBody";
import TableCell from "@material-ui/core/TableCell";
import TableRow from "@material-ui/core/TableRow";
import Table from "@material-ui/core/Table";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
// import { MuiThemeProvider } from "material-ui/styles";

import Dialog from "@material-ui/core/Dialog";
import DialogActions from "@material-ui/core/DialogActions";
import DialogContent from "@material-ui/core/DialogContent";
import DialogContentText from "@material-ui/core/DialogContentText";
import DialogTitle from "@material-ui/core/DialogTitle";
import ExerciseList from "./ExerciseList";

// import EditWorkoutItem from "./EditWorkoutItem";
import * as workoutActionCreators from '../../actions';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { connect } from "react-redux";

import moment from "moment";

export default class WorkoutItem extends Component {
  state = {
    open: false
  };

  handleSelectedPanel = () => {
    this.props.onSelectedPanel(this.props.workout.id);
  };

  // Opens the page
  handleClickOpen = () => {
    this.setState({ open: true });
  };

  // Cancels the changes and closes the page
  handleClose = () => {
    this.setState({ open: false });
  };

  deleteWorkout = id => {
    console.log(this);
    this.setState({ open: false });
    this.props.removeWorkout(id);
  };

  render() {
    const { workout } = this.props;
    const { id, name, duration, exerciselist } = workout;
    const date = moment(workout.date).format("L");

    return (
      <ExpansionPanel style={styles.panel} id={id} onChange={this.handleSelectedPanel}>
        <ExpansionPanelSummary>
          <Typography variant="button" style={styles.header}>
            {name}
          </Typography>
          <Typography variant="button" style={styles.header}>
            {date}
          </Typography>
          <Typography align="right" style={styles.header}>
            ~{duration} mins
          </Typography>
        </ExpansionPanelSummary>
        <ExpansionPanelDetails>
          <Table size="medium" style={styles.table}>
            <TableHead>
              <TableRow>
                <TableCell padding="none">Name</TableCell>
                <TableCell padding="none" align="right">
                  # of sets
                </TableCell>
                <TableCell padding="none" align="right">
                  average reps
                </TableCell>
                <TableCell padding="none" align="right">
                  weight
                </TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            </TableHead>
            <TableBody>
              {exerciselist.map(exercise => (
                <ExerciseList key={exercise.id} exercise={exercise} />
              ))}
            </TableBody>
          </Table>
          <ExpansionPanelActions disableSpacing style={styles.actionButton}>
            {/* <MuiThemeProvider>
              <EditWorkoutItem id={id} />
            </MuiThemeProvider> */}
            <>
              <Button size="small" disableRipple onClick={this.handleClickOpen}>
                Remove
              </Button>
              <Dialog
                open={this.state.open}
                onClose={this.handleClose}
                aria-labelledby="alert-dialog-title"
                aria-describedby="alert-dialog-description"
              >
                <DialogTitle id="alert-dialog-title">
                  {"Are you sure?"}
                </DialogTitle>
                <DialogContent>
                  <DialogContentText id="alert-dialog-description">
                    This will permanently remove the workout. This action cannot
                    be undone.
                  </DialogContentText>
                </DialogContent>
                <DialogActions>
                  <Button onClick={this.handleClose} color="primary">
                    Cancel
                  </Button>
                  <Button
                    onClick={() => this.deleteWorkout(id)}
                    color="primary"
                    autoFocus
                  >
                    Yes, Remove It
                  </Button>
                </DialogActions>
              </Dialog>
            </>
          </ExpansionPanelActions>
        </ExpansionPanelDetails>
      </ExpansionPanel>
    );
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return { ...bindActionCreators(workoutActionCreators, dispatch) };
};

connect(
  null,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(WorkoutItem);
```

action:

```
export const removeWorkout = id => ({ type: 'REMOVE_WORKOUT', id })
```

reducer:

```
        case 'REMOVE_WORKOUT':
            console.log(action.id)
            return state = {
                ...state,
                workoutlist: state.workoutlist.filter((workout) => workout.id !== action.id)
        }
```

no error message. but its returning the correct id when i use console.log and it does close the textbox. thats how i know it stops at the function

Comment: if you use `mapDispatchToProps` you cannot call the functions directly. You call it  `this.props.removeWorkout(id)`

Comment: @keysl why i do that, it throws the error: Uncaught TypeError: this.props.removeWorkout is not a function when i click 'Yes, Remove it' button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The first main problem** is that you are not calling correct "dispatcher" function, but the original one.

Change your  deleteWorkout into this:

```js
deleteWorkout = id => {
    console.log(id);
    this.setState({ open: false });
    this.props.removeWorkout(id);
  };
```

**The second main problem** is that you are not exporting connected Redux container but your React component which is still unconnected to Redux.

Remove "export default" from your class declaration:

```js
class WorkoutItem extends Component {
// ...
```

and add it to the Redux container:

```js
export default connect(
    null,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(WorkoutItem);
```

**EDIT** (This is optional change for realizing the idea of the bindActorCreators function. The bindActorCreators can take also single action creator as the first parameter).
And also it seems you are passing single action creator as the first parameter to the redux function bindActionCreators, but the function takes a map of action creators instead.
https://redux.js.org/api/bindactioncreators

You have two options how to fix it:

1. do not use the bindActionCreators (it's better if you are the redux beginner)

```js
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return { removeWorkout: (id) => dispatch(removeWorkout(id)) };
};
```

2. use the bindActionCreators correctly

```js
// you need to import your action crerators in single object
import * as workoutActionCreators from 'path_to_your_action_creators';

// ...

// bind all action creators with dispatch function and the bound action creators map to props
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return { ...bindActionCreators(workoutActionCreators, dispatch) };
};
```

Comment: I tried that and described what happened in my comment above

Comment: You had another problem, sorry I didn't see it first time. Look at my edit after: 'And also it seems ...'

Comment: I tried both of those ways and they still returned the same exact error... Would that mean im doing something wrong somewhere else completely?

Comment: Probably, can you post whole file WorkoutItem.js (with imports) and files where you initialize redux in application (store, reducers, ...)?

Comment: Yeah, i appreciate the help! I've been lost on this for too long lol

Comment: I found the second main problem, see my edit after 'The second main problem ...'. I also found out that according to the redux documentation, the bindActionCreators can take the single action creator as the first parameter, but I think such a usage is actually not following the real idea of the bindActorCreators  function.